# setting current cell in datagridview in load event not working in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is my code for setting the current cell:

```
dvFromAlloc.CurrentCell = dvFromAlloc(1, 0)
```

How ever this is not working in load event, Why is it not working?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please explain when the DGV is being populated? and why you think that it does not work (are you getting an error)?

Comment: @varocarbas: Hi sir, The dgv is being populated in load event, I do not get any error, It is just not working in the load event.

Comment: And why you think that it does not work? Because if the column/row is there and you don't get any error, this code should work fine anywhere.

Comment: I do not know sir, But if I put it in Shown event, or in button event, its working, I don't know why is it not working in load event, Thank you sir.

Comment: Yes, I got that. But my question is how you know that "it does not work"? What test are you doing to confirm this point?

Comment: The test that I'm doing is that when I put the code in the load form and debug it, the cell remains on the first column and first row, but when I put the code in the shown event or button event, the cell is on the second column and first row.

Comment: Sorry, not able to replicate. Perhaps some other person might be able to help (writing down your exact code in the Form load method might be helpful). There shouldn't be any difference. What you might get is an error (because the GUI wasn't loaded yet or because the column/row is not present) but just not getting it to work is certainly weird.

Comment: Ahh ok sir, I might give it a try to fix this one and tell you if I have a solution for this, Thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Try this Code

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0];
```

Or Verify this link

[Data Grid View Cell Focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900359/data-grid-view-cell-focused)

Answer (score 0):

DGV.Focus()
  DGV.CurrentCell = DGV.Rows(0).Cells(2)

Answer (score 0):

Set the Current Cell :

```
dvFromAlloc.CurrentCell = dvFromAlloc.Item(1, 5)
```

or

```
dvFromAlloc.CurrentCell = dvFromAlloc.Item("ColumnName", 5)
```

and you can directly focus with Editing by:

```
dvFromAlloc.BeginEdit(true)
```