# How to focus cell in datagridview vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Event  :  DataGridView1_CellEndEdit

```
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2)
    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
```

I want to focus cell  row 0  column 2 for edit

I edit cell and enter .
datagridview focus row 0 column 2 .
And i type   it not focus row 0 column 2
it focus row 1 colum 2

it not work by this code.

Sorry.my english isn’t that good. Thank you.

I edit cell and enter:

[image]

datagridview focus row 0 column 2:

[image]

it focus row 1 colum 2:

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900359/data-grid-view-cell-focused

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question that you want to move to next `cell` of `datagridview` when you press `Enter` key. Try this

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, iRow + 1];
                else
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Cells[0];
        }
        else
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
            SendKeys.Send("{left}");
        }

    }
```